# Share URL to app in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

In the share option for my app, I have a standard UIActivityViewController. One of the activity items should be a link to the app, so that they can share the app. However, since the app is not released, I don't know how I'll get a URL to it in the app store

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = @"Check out this card I made with this app.";
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([_cardView snapshot]);
    NSURL *URL = ... // I want a URL to my app in the app store here
    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:@[message, data, URL]
                                                    applicationActivities:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityController
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:nil];
}
```

There is an app called "100Balls" on the AppStore that does the same thing with their sharing option, and the URL I see them use is "www.AppStore.com/100Balls".

Given the name of my app is "MyApp", and the app name doesn't already exist, will this work if I use "www.AppStore.com/MyApp" as the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just tested my application and have never used `AppStore.com` before. It linked to my application correctly. It will be the name that you use on the app store.

To prove it: `http://appstore.com/facebook` `http://appstore.com/snapchat`

The real link can be found before you application is approved by heading to `iTunes connect` clicking on your application -> Under `Links` there is `View in app store`

It will have a link like: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id768628639?ls=1&mt=8`

As the user never sees the end link, I would be inclined to use the real link found on `iTunes connect`.